# MOSFET switching loss calculation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, switching-losses

I read the "[PFC boost converter design guide](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/InfineonApplicationNote_PFCCCMBoostConverterDesignGuide-AN-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a56eed8014a62c75a923b05)"

There is an equation that is used to calculate the switching turn-on loss.
Does anyone know how to get that equation?

[image]

Comment: What fundamental equations did you consider? Put in your question, so we know you tried and know something already.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I have no idea how to get this equation. 
I try to search for some documents, but I don't find the document which talks ing about it.

Comment: So you don't know any FET equations or capacitor energy equations

Comment: you posted the document in question